# NVMe PCIe Hard Disk on Freescale LS2080A not recognised

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci, pci-e

I have a Freescale LS2080 box for which I am developing a custom linux 4.1.8 kernel using the Freescale Yocto project.

I have an NVMe hard disk attached to the LS2080 via a PCIe card, but the disk is not recognised when I boot up the board with my custom linux kernel.

I plugged the same combination of NVMe disk and PCIe card into a linux 3.16.7 desktop PC and it was detected and mounted without problem.

When building the LS2080 kernel using the Yocto project, I have enabled the NVMe block device driver and I have verified that this module is present in the kernel when booting on the board.

The PCIe slot on the board is working fine because I have tried it with a PCIe Ethernet card and a PCIe SATA disk.

I suspect that I am missing something in the kernel configuration or device tree, but I'm not sure what. When I add the NVMe driver to the kernel using menuconfig, the NVMe driver dependencies are supposed to be resolved.

Can anyone provide insight into what I am missing?

Comment: Did you try to add the nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500 attribute? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78090806/5081063

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that PCIe device is recognized using lspci.

If device is not shown in lspci list this is enumeration problem, to check the error use PCIe analyzers.

If the device is shown in the list then simply add the device vendor id and device ID to NVMe driver and recompile to load the driver for your device.