# Installing Linux on Acer extensa 215-21 does not recognize the hard disk (NVME)

Tags: linux-kernel, nvme

I've tried several times to install different distro Linux on Acer extensa 215-21 with hard disk SSD NVME.
After putting Ubuntu into a live USB it does not see the hard disk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is about the NVME hard disk on Acer which requires different settings in the linux kernel to read it properly.
I've solved it with the following steps:

- when the live USB starts and the GRUB appears type `E` to show the linux settings
- edit the line next to `linux` adding at the end `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500` before the dashes at the end of the line
- type `Ctrl + X` to run the linux distro with the new settings

With these new settings, the OS will be able to read the hard disk.

Well, after the installation the problem will be present in the newly installed OS, then, when you remove the live USB and run the OS press the `Shift` key before the OS starts to open the GRUB and follow the same steps above to run it with the nvme settings.

Instead of following the steps on startup every time you can make permanent the linux kernel settings of your GRUB by changing it via the terminal using the following command:

```bash
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and change the line

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="whatever"`

adding the nvme conf

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="whatever nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500"`

save the changes using `Ctrl+O` and close the file using `Ctrl+X`, then run the following command to update the grub:

```bash
sudo update-grub
```

That's all.